# Handler not refreshing the grid view in android

Tags: android, gridview, handler, android-cursoradapter

In my Android app I have a grid showing images as items. When I click a button the items should be change their positions. I am populating this grid through a cursor adapter. Previously it was working fine but was taking some time to change the positions of the images and refresh the grid once again. So for that i implemented a progress dialog, so that user could understand that something is going on.

Here is my code so far.

My Handler

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
switch (msg.what) {
    case PROGRESS_DIALOG_HANDLER_ID:
        progressDialog.dismiss(); //ProgressDialog
        DBAdapter adapter = new DBAdapter(SplittedImageActivity.this);
        adapter.open();
        Cursor cursor = adapter.getAllImages();
        adapter.close();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        cursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor); //My cursor adapter
        gridView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        cursor.close();
```

My onclick method

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SplittedImageActivity.this, "", "Please wait...");
new Thread(){
        public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        DBAdapter adapter = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        adapter.open();
        int childs = gridView.getChildCount(), oldPosition, newPotision;
        newPotision = childs-1;
        for(int i=0 ; i<childs ; i++){
            oldPosition = random.nextInt(m_cGridView.getChildCount());
            adapter.updatePosition(oldPosition, newPotision); //updates the position of the images in database
            newPotision = oldPosition;
        }
        adapter.close();
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(PROGRESS_DIALOG_HANDLER_ID);
    };
}.start();
```

**Problems:**

The progress dialog is showing eprfectly, the positions are also changed in the database. but the gridview is not refreshing. I mean after all works done the progress dialog disappears and the screen becomes blank.

Please help me where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are assigning a new adapter on  the handler, but not calling to NotifyDataSetChanged() on the main thread, that's maybe why is not updating the grid.

Also, why not use AsyncTasks?

```
public class LoadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    Context context;

    public LoadAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;         
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... v) {
        DBAdapter adapter = new DBAdapter(context);
        adapter.open();
        int childs = gridView.getChildCount(), oldPosition, newPotision;
        newPotision = childs-1;
        for(int i=0 ; i<childs ; i++){
                    oldPosition = random.nextInt(m_cGridView.getChildCount());
                    adapter.updatePosition(oldPosition, newPotision); //updates the position of the images in database
                    newPotision = oldPosition;
        }
        adapter.close();

        DBAdapter adapter = new DBAdapter(context);
        adapter.open();
        Cursor cursor = adapter.getAllImages();
        adapter.close();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        cursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor); //My cursor adapter
        gridView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        cursor.close();                
        return true;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        if (success) {
            //This will be executed on the main activity thread
            cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            showError();
        }
    }

}
```